# Running some code only if it's tested by cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here, but I need to put an if statement in my application code that takes one branch if the current request is from cypress, and the other if not.

---

(off-topic: I know full well that usually this is a Very-Bad-Idea®, because you want to test the app exactly as it is seen by end users. On the other hand, we live in the real world, with limited time, and sometimes a small bad idea is allowed)

---

One way seems to be to manually change the user agent or add headers to the cypress calls, I just want to know if there is a very obvious (and better) way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the app from a Cypress test, the `window` object has a property called `Cypress`.

So inside the app you can test for this property

```js
if (window.Cypress) {
  // testing is active
  ...
} else {
  // testing not active
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag to indicate you are running the application through cypress.

for example, using the session storage:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setFlag', (flag: string, value: string | boolean) => {
  cy.window().then((w) => {
    w.sessionStorage.setItem('flags.' + flag, value.toString());
  });
});


//in the test
before(() => {
  cy.setFlag("test_mode", true)
})
```

And in your app

```
if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("flags.test_mode"))
  //do stuff
else
  //do other stuff
```

You could also implement some sort of service that will manage it.

```
export class FlagsService {
  public get isNotProd() {
    return window.location.origin !== "ProdDomain";
  }

  get<T>(flag: string): T | null {
    if (this.isNotProd) {
      const key = 'flags.' + flag;
      const rawFlag = window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
      if (rawFlag) {
        return rawFlag as unknown as T;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. If not for the `window.Cypress` solution, this would definitely be the one!